# Trying to toggle divs with JS after calling a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am wondering whether this is possible:

I have a page.  The user clicks a link and that calls a PHP script.  The PHP script returns true or false.

Depending on the true or false, I was hoping to be able to toggle a div.

I am wondering whether I need to do it the AJAX way? How do people usually accomplish this?
Seems pretty common.

I am using this YUI library already:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.2r1/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css&2.8.2r1/build/base/base-min.css">
```

Comment: well, that all depends on what your code looks like. If you could provide it, that would be helpful to us. It is entirely possible, we just don't know what you are trying. Are you checking for errors? And by toggle, do you mean being able to show/hide the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, very easy, no need for Ajax.  Here's two ways:

Using straight PHP:

```
<?php

if($test) {
  echo "<div>Content...</div>";
}

?>
```

Or, using inline Javascript (in the PHP script), assuming you have a `<div id='targetDiv'>` in your HTML, and a `$testVar` in your PHP:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggle(testVar) { 
  if(testVar) { document.getElementById('targetDiv').style.display = ""; }
  else { document.getElementById('targetDiv').style.display = "none"; } 
}

window.onload = function() { toggle(<?php echo $testVar; ?>); } 
</script>
```

The second method can be easily altered to degrade gracefully.

Comment: Cheers @Genadinik, glad it worked out. BTW fixed the last line error should be `echo $testVar`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery:

```
$.post('/path/to/url', {data: 'some data'}, function(data) {
    if (data) $('#some-div').show();
    else $('#some-div').hide();
}, 'json');
```

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(true);
```

For more information see:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: My application is using the YUI library. Is there a way to do this using that? – Genadinik 0 secs ago edit

Comment: @Genadinik, what version of YUI?

Comment: I just update my original question with the YUI call I am making

Comment: @Genadinik, it looks like you are only using the YUI CSS library, consider using the jQuery JavaScript library in conjunction with YUI CSS

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use AJAX to create a good flow in your site. Instead of implementing your own AJAX handling functions, you could use one of the big JavaScript frameworks, I recommend http://jquery.com/. There, you can read about (and see examples of) `jQuery.ajax` - http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

This should get you started, but the main idea is to bind that link to an AJAX function, that will call your PHP script, and based on the contents of the returned data, toggle your DIVs on/off.

Good luck!

Comment: actually my application is using the YUI library.  Is there a way to do this using that?

Comment: @Genadinik: I don't know anything about YUI, but there's a nice tutorial on http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/ I've encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Set the php script to add a hidden field ...  such as...

```
<input type="hidden" id="passed-value" value="passed-val-is-true" />
```

Then in your Javascript when you fire the toggle event .. check that element ...

In jQuery would be something like this ...

```
$foo.click(( if (passed-value.value === "passed-val-is-true") { foo.toggle(); }
```

Sorry for syntax .. but you should get the general idea.

Also, if you need it to do without page reload, i would def recommend Ajax (pref via jQuery)